# Why is my data not persisted/accessible in an Spring-Boot integration-test with HTTPGraphQLTester and TestEntityManager

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing, graphql-java

I have a bare-bones Spring-Boot app with some GraphQL endpoints and a Postgres database and want to run an integration test against an endpoint. It should find an entity by its ID and does so without a problem when I send a request manually via Postman. However when I write an integration test for the controller it doesn't. The data seems to be saved after using
**TestEntityManager** (or the **JpaRepository** directly) an I get the entity back with its ID. I then stick that ID into a query with **HttpGraphQlTester** which fails with an empty result/null. I traced it with the debugger and discovered that when the endpoint calls the repository to retrieve the entity with the given ID it gets null or when I look at all the repo-contents it's just an empty list. So my data seems to be accessible in my test but not in my repo/service. Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

#### Test

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureHttpGraphQlTester
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
@Transactional
public class BackboneTreeControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  HttpGraphQlTester tester;

  @Autowired
  private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

  @Test
  void findTaxon() {
    Taxon taxon = Taxon.builder()
      .path(Arrays.asList("path", "to", "taxon"))
      .nameCanonical("Cocos nucifera")
      .authorship("Me")
      .extinct(false)
      .numDescendants(1l)
      .numOccurrences(1l)
      .build();

    Taxon savedTaxon = testEntityManager.persistFlushFind(taxon); // (1)

    this.tester.documentName("queries")
      .operationName("FindTaxon")
      .variable("taxonId", savedTaxon.getId())
      .execute()
      .path("findTaxon.authorship")
      .entity(String.class)
      .isEqualTo("Me");
```

1. the testEntityManager returns successfully with an ID.

#### Query

```
query FindTaxon($taxonId: ID!) {
    findTaxon(id: $taxonId) {
        authorship
    }
}
```

#### Controller

```
@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BackboneTreeController {

  private final TaxonService taxonService;

  @QueryMapping
  public Taxon findTaxon(@Argument Integer id) {
    Optional<Taxon> taxon = taxonService.findTaxon(id);
    return taxon.orElse(null);
  }

}
```

#### Service

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TaxonService {

  private final TaxonRepository taxonRepository;

  public Optional<Taxon> findTaxon(Integer id) {
    return taxonRepository.findById(id); // (2)
  }
}
```

2. This is where I would expect the repo to return the entity but it does not. Also using `.findAll` here returns an empty list.

#### Repository

```
@Repository
public interface TaxonRepository extends JpaRepository<Taxon, Integer> {
}
```

Note that everything works fine when I just run the app and send the exact same query manually!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `HttpGraphQlTester` but I'd assume that it generates requests which then get processed in a separate thread.

That thread won't see the changes made in the test because they aren't committed yet.

If this is the reason resolve it by putting the setup in it's own transaction, for example by using `TransactionTemplate`.